# Opening android app from webpage

Tags: android, html, web

I have a webpage and i made an app from my webpage.
My question is can i open my app from the webpage?
My app package name is: com.myapp.comic and if user visits my webpage there will be a link to Open in app, like in instagram, is it possible?
My app is not on the Play Market.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is called [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

here's a nice guide  https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes/